# Excel filtering by multiple begins with characters

Tags: excel, filtering

The title explains most of it, but I was wondering how I would do a filter that selects records that begin with multiple characters such as: "H, E, R, B." I know you can set up a filter for a single character but I can't find any documentation on filtering for multiple individual characters. For clarification, it would give me all the records that start with H, all that start with E, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A2,1)="H",LEFT(A2,1)="E",LEFT(A2,1)="R",LEFT(A2,1)="B"),1,0)
```

copy downwards and filter on column **B** values equal to 1:

[image]

Comment: Just an FYI, the `OR` can be shortened to `OR(LEFT(A2)={"H","E","R","B"})`  and I do not believe it even needs the Ctrl-Shift-Enter on older versions to work.

Comment: @ScottCraner ..........................thanks.......................................